# My python extension of VS Code is not loading in my "D Drive" but is working fine in "C Drive"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ide

Python extension (provided by Microsoft) in VS Code is not working in my "D Drive" but is working in my "C Drive". I am getting the error stating,
"The extension 'Python' took a very long time to complete its last operation and it has prevented other extensions from running" see screenshot by  [clicking here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjgNr.png)

Recently I received an update from windows (related to windows defender improvement and after updating, my Python extension stopped loading and is taking forever.
But it is working in my C Drive (Where my python and VS Code is installed). I have tried reinstalling both of them, and I even formatted my whole windows 10, but still no luck...Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I have found its solution.

Simply add the paths of python files such as:

```
C:\Users\kkaus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\
C:\Users\kkaus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\
```

to the system variable instead of the user variable to access the interpreter globally.